# Making a 1 on 1 copy of a list

Tags: enterprise-wiki

It seems to me that the answer to this problem should be rather straightforward, but I'm having some trouble finding it...
I currently have an Enterprise Wiki, it contains the regular "Pages" list, which you can find by going Ribbon -> Page -> View All Pages.

Now, I want that list to be on my Wiki's frontpage. I tried setting the list's url as the welcome page, but it wouldn't accept that. However I can't find a clear answer on how I can put a copy of the Pages list on my welcome page while keeping it 1 on 1 with the original.
I'm using SharePoint 2013 by the way.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've managed to add the list to my welcome page using an App Part, but the view doesn't stick. I have 2 custom columns that don't get displayed.

Comment: You should be able to define the view in the Web Part options panel. By default, I think the view is "Current", which means "whatever the individual user last chose".

Comment: Thanks for the reply John. Sadly, that doesn't seem to work. When I select the "All Documents" view, I get the message: "Switching to a different view removes changes you have made to this view and may disable Web Part connections that depend on columns in this view." Once I accept the change, the copied list's connection is broken, as stated.

Comment: The problem seems to be that I can't save the Pages library as a template. This is an option for basically any list or library I try, except for this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem in a rather embarrassingly simple way. When trying to set the homepage via Site Settings, the form does not accept the URL.

However, when on the page itself, I'm able to select Make Homepage in the Ribbon and for some reason it DOES accept that...

This solved my problem, but I was sadly unable to make a copy of the Pages Library and place that on another page. Which was probably the more interesting part of this problem.